# Consulta Select en php a mi base de datos mysql no me devuelve el registro ya que no reconoce el caracter "&"

Tags: php, android, mysql

Estoy realizando una consulta select a mi base de datos mysql para traer los registros de los usuarios que tengo registrados. El campo de consulta para el select es el nombre y el id, en el campo nombre de la tabla hay registros que poseen caracteres como "&" o "ë" o "'", razon por la cual no me devuelve los registros que estan en la tabla.

La consulta se realiza desde una app android.

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

//Invocar conexion a host de base de datos
require_once 'mysqlLogin.php';

//Variables de busqueda metodo GET
$id=$_GET["id"];
$empresa=$_GET["empresa"];

// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada 
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username,$password, $database);

// comprobar si existe algún error
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

//enable utf8!
$mysqli -> query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");


// Creamos la consulta SQL
$sql = 'SELECT id_empresa, paquete_empresa, categoria_empresa, nombre_empresa from directorio where id_empresa=? and nombre_empresa=?';


// La preparamos
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
// bindeamos los datos
$stmt->bind_param('is', $id,$empresa );
// Ejecutamos la consulta
$stmt->execute();
// Recuperamos los datos
$stmt->bind_result($id, $paquete, $categoria, $nombre);

//Declarar arrelgo
$datos=array();

// comprobar si devolvio registros
if ($stmt){

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //Crear arreglo temporal para agregar valores de las columnas
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id_empresa"] = $id;
        $tmp["paquete_empresa"] = $paquete;
        $tmp["categoria_empresa"] = $categoria;
        $tmp["nombre_empresa"] = $nombre;

        //Agregar a arreglo variable temporal
        array_push($datos, $tmp);

    }
    // Liberar resultados
    $stmt->close();

    //Convertir respuesta a Json
    echo json_encode($datos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


}
else{
    echo 'No se encontraron resultados';
    exit;
}


// Cerrar la conexión
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

**Base de Datos:Configuración**

[image: Configuracion de la base de datos]

Comment: Falta código para poder revisar lo que está ocurriendo... por ejemplo:  ¿cómo preparas la consulta, como le pasas los parámetros, cómo la ejecutas, cómo recuperas los resultados? ¿Cómo obtienes los valores que servirán de criterio `WHERE` en la consulta?  ¿Para qué aplicas todos esos `SET` al inicio? .... bastaría con que apliques el charset al crear el objeto de conexión.

Answer (score 2):

Vega, tu código no es coherente en su lógica, ni tampoco lo es con los encabezados.

Si tú indicas un tipo de encabezado, significa que, ocurra lo que ocurra, deberás devolver ese tipo de dato en el código (en este caso un `json`).

En cuanto al charset`con que solamente lo indiques en el`header` y en el objeto de conexión a la base de datos, bastaría. No estoy seguro, pero me parece que ese juego de comandos que le mandas a la base de datos podría dar problemas.

En el siguiente código yo uso una variable llamada `$arrDatos`, que irá recogiendo todas las posibles eventualidades del código y al final se imprimirá **solamente esa variable, como un json, con lo que tenga.**

De ese modo el código queda normalizado, pues tú no puedes poner un `header` json y luego hacer un `echo` de una cadena normalita, como haces más de una vez en tu código.

Prueba esta solución, la cual espero te sirva. Espero no haber cometido ningún error tipográfico, si es así, podrás detectarlo rápido.

Espero tu comentario de vuelta cuando lo hayas probado :)

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

//Invocar conexion a host de base de datos
require_once 'mysqlLogin.php';

//Variables de busqueda metodo GET
$id=$_GET["id"];
$empresa=$_GET["empresa"];

// Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username,$password, $database);

/*Array para recoger lo que ocurra en el código*/
$arrDatos=array();
// comprobar si existe algún error
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    $arrDatos["error"]= "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: ".PHP_EOL
        . $mysqli->connect_errno . PHP_EOL
        ." Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = 'SELECT id_empresa, paquete_empresa, categoria_empresa, nombre_empresa from directorio where id_empresa=? and nombre_empresa=?';
    // La preparamos
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt){
        // bindeamos los datos
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $id,$empresa );
        // Ejecutamos la consulta
        $stmt->execute();
        // Recuperamos los datos
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $paquete, $categoria, $nombre);

        // comprobar si devolvio registros
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $arrDatos["id_empresa"] = $id;
            $arrDatos["paquete_empresa"] = $paquete;
            $arrDatos["categoria_empresa"] = $categoria;
            $arrDatos["nombre_empresa"] = $nombre;
        }
        /*Operador ternario para poner un mensaje en el array si no hay registros, o dejarlo tal cual*/
        (!$arrDatos)?$arrDatos ["error"]= "Error, no se encontraron registros" : "";

        // Liberar resultados
        $stmt->close();

    }else{

        $arrDatos["error"]="Error preparando la consulta: ".$mysqli->error;
    }

    // Cerrar la conexión
    $mysqli->close();
}

//Convertir respuesta a Json
echo json_encode($arrDatos);

?>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero sigue igual no me devuelve el registro. me da vacio la respuesta.

Comment: @jvega si da vacío no es problema del código entonces sino de que los datos que buscas no existen. O no está recibiendo bien los valores en el `GET` o algo de eso. ¿Qué parte del array está tomando la que dice que no se encontraron datos?

Comment: El registro si existe, lo que sucede es que esa cadena de texto contiene el caracter "&".

Comment: @jvega creo que ahora entiendo tu situación. Al usar `GET` los datos se envían serializados usando justamente el carácter `&` como separador de cada par *llave&valor*. En ese caso, lo 1º es usar `POST` para enviar los datos en vez de `GET` y segundo, si estás usando `serialize`, puedes cambiar por `serializeArray`, que te enviará los datos así + o -: `[{name: "actor_nombre", value: "Pedro&Pablo"}, {name: "actor_apellido", value: "Test"}, {name: "actor_nombre", value: "María&Ana"}, {name: "actor_apellido", value: "Test2"}]`. Sólo que tendrás que cambiar la forma de recuperarlos...

Comment: ... otra cosa que podrías hacer es construir *a mano* los datos que quieres enviar (enviándolos siempre por POST) y entonces recuperarlos normalmente, o enviar un objeto JSON y parsearlo del lado de PHP. Cualquiera de esas formas permitiría que recibas los datos tal cual: `Pedro&Pablo`, `María&Ana`, etc.